# I'm not sure if I'm using instance variables correctly here - RGB based objects (Java)

Tags: java, object, methods, instance-variables

I'm struggling to figure out the interactions in using instance variables within objects, but being able to change objects with methods that take other object parameters. The program is supposed to use a Color object with int parameters for the R, G, and B values to associate itself with a color.

For example:

```
   public void add(Color c) {
        red = red + c.red;
        blue = blue + c.blue;
        green = green + c.green;

        if (red > 255) {
            red = 255;
        }
        if (green > 255) {
            green = 255;
        }
        if (blue > 255) {
            blue = 255;
        }
    }
```

I don't know if it's an issue with the format I'm attempting to use, but I can't seem to figure out where exactly I'm tripping up. For reference, this is the constructor I'm trying to use:

```
    public Color(int r, int g, int b) {
        red = r;
        green = g;
        blue = b;
        if (r > 255) {
            red = 255;
        }
        if (r < 0) {
            red = 0;
        }
        if (g > 255) {
            green = 255;
        }
        if (g < 0) {
            green = 0;
        }
        if (b > 255) {
            blue = 255;
        }
        if (b < 0) {
            blue = 0;
        }

    }
```

This was the test I was running to try to see if my methods were working:

```
    public final static Color RED = new Color(255, 0, 0);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Color test = new Color (0,0,0);

        test.add(RED);
        System.out.println(test.red + test.green + test.blue);
    }
```

However this just yielded 0. Any help or insight to what I'm not understanding would be wonderful!

Comment: I have a gut feeling that it might be due to the fact I'm not using get'er / set'er methods? Are these basically required or?

Comment: Your constructor doesn't set `red`, `blue` or `green` when they are in range.

Comment: I edited that accordingly! Thanks a bunch. I think my issue would now be with my toString method for hexidecimal formatting. Other than this any glaring issues?

Comment: I just ran the code and got 255 - which is what I would expect to get.  Were you getting the 0 when the constructor wasn't setting the initial values?

Comment: I think you should post the whole code, not just these snippets, as it seems to be OK now; in particular, how are `red`, `blue` and `green` declared? Also Rushilwiz's advice is worth following.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any glaring issues with the code, but I would recommend writing a toString method for the `Color` class along with some getters and setters. However, this should nicely format it as a hex string (`#rrggbb`).

```
public String toString() {
    String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", red, green, blue)
}
```